Why don't threads close when using httpx in asynchronous functions?
I'm running python code (3.10.14) in jupyter notebook. However, when I run an asynchronous function (AsyncClient.get(...) from httpx v0.27.0) in the cell , I see that one of the threads is still alive - even though the context manager has been closed. If I understand correctly, this can lead to problems with memory leaks etc.
The code I run is as follows (jupyter notebook):
import httpx
import threading
import time

async def fetch():
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url)
        return response.text

print("Threads before", threading.active_count())
res = await fetch()

time.sleep(2) # small sleep to make sure maybe it will close
print("Threads after", threading.active_count())

Output:
Threads before 7
Threads after 8

In this case, I expect the number of threads before and after execution to remain the same.
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or why my understanding is incorrect would help me a lot. Thank you for all answers.
